# how to upload the data created by SQLite to a MySQL server?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, cordova

I´m currently creating an android app through a form that saves data in a table with SQLite.

I need to include a function that when the client click "upload" the data in that table get on the actual table MySQL server and remove the table created by SQLite.

Anyone have any example of how to do this, if you could automate the action when the device has Internet would be perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if there was something that can do that out of the box. You'll need program something to extract the data from SQLite, format insert queries for MySQL and run them.